# Java objects within class not main

Tags: java, class, object, implementation

I was wondering if it was possible for example to create automaticly 2 objects from a class into a new class, and then use a main class create a new object of the new class you just created.

For example:

```
Public class Trafficlight(){
 String color;

 public trafficLight(Somecolor){
  this.color = Somecolor;
 }

}


public class CrossRoad(){
 public CrossRoad(){
 trafficLight trafficLightNr1 = new  trafficLight("green");
  trafficLight  trafficLightNr2 = new  trafficLight("red");
 }
}

Public class main
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    CrossRoad SomeCrossRoad = new CrossRoad();
    CrossRoad SomeOtherCrossRoad = new CrossRoad();   
    }
}
```

Ps: if there are some mistakes in my syntax, i just wrote it fast. I'm just curious if this is possible to create something like this.

Comment: Of course.  Why wouldn't it work?

Comment: Yes, you can create object that contain other objects.

Comment: Yes it is possible. If you have tried it before this question would never arised. Looks like the problem is in your wrong posted code: `Public` instead of `public`, wrong constructor names (class `Trafficlight` has a `trafficlight` *constructor*) and on... By the way, after fixing the codes, you would probably want to add some `System.out.println` in order to show to yourself how the program is behaving (or debug it line by line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, but you will need to store those objects in the class, otherwise they will be lost when the scope of the Constructor is finished.

```
public class CrossRoad(){
    TrafficLight trafficLightNr1;
    TrafficLight trafficLightNr2;
    public CrossRoad(){
        trafficLightNr1 = new TrafficLight("green");
        trafficLightNr2 = new TrafficLight("red");
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel so embarrassed,As you can see, i'm still green behind the ears. i was looking in my syntax what i could have done possibly wrong, i never taught i forgot to store them, I humbly appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem, just be careful with these type of questions.  If you hadn't written the code already it probably would have been downvoted to nonexistence for lack of trying :)